# Is there a way to include a calculated priority in Rally?

Tags: rally

I am trying to use a "Rubric" of sorts to prioritize features (portfolio items) in Rally. Essentially, I want to create 4-5 custom fields with numerical values (1-10). Based on these fields, I want to calculate a priority which would be a sum of the values in the custom fields. I want my portfolio items to be prioritized in descending order of the calculated field. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create several custom fields with numerical values, add up those values and set the value of another field to the sum.

However, it is not possible to build that logic in Rally UI, where fields cannot be customized to use a custom roll-up mechanism. You may add up the values and set a value of another field to the sum of those values on individual artifacts programmatically. You have to write code, e.g a Rally custom app using [AppSDK2](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/) (javascript), or [other toolkits](https://github.com/RallyTools) that will use update convenience method provided by the toolkit to set the value after it was calculated by your code.

If a user in UI sets values to those 4-5 custom fields, your code can then query artifacts on which those values are set, add them up and set the custom priority field to the sum. This custom script can be run periodically to update the values of custom priority field. A custom grid, or a grid in your javascript custom app written with AppSDK2 can be sorted by the priority field.